# memwatch and C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Has anyone ever used [memwatch](http://www.linkdata.se/sourcecode/memwatch/) with C++? The documentation that I have mentions only using it with C. I am curious if it works just as good for C++ code when looking for memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the home page you linked to says *"Rudimentary support for C++ (disabled by default, use with care!)"* so I'd say... use with care. :-)

That said, it should probably work "well enough" but the output may be cryptic because of how C++ handles symbols differently than C.

Comment: Yeah, my main concerns are the presentation and validity of the output.

Comment: At the very least you may get gibberish symbol names. @waffleman

Answer (score 0):

1. change your file `memwatch.c` to `memwatch.cpp`
2. define the macro `MEMWATCH` and `MW_STDIO`
3. `include memwatch.h` and define n`ew->mwNew delete->mwDelete` in
   your program files

Tell me if works